# Constant java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space Arquillian + Wildfly 8.1

Tags: java, maven, wildfly, jboss-arquillian, wildfly-8

Hi started a new project.  One of the first things i wanted to do was get Arquillian set up and rolling.
I have a couple controllers and JSF forms written.

The process of loading up the dependencies

```
final File[] files = Maven.resolver().loadPomFromFile("pom.xml").importRuntimeAndTestDependencies().resolve()
                .withTransitivity().asFile();
LOG.info(files.toString());
final WebArchive archive = ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class, "main-webapp-arq.war"); etc...
```

run

```
mvn -PprofileName package
```

everything seems to go swimmingly, i see it starting to launch wildfly, then i see it deploy the app, the startup beans fire then i get:

```
....
[0m[0m20:37:30,025 INFO  [org.apache.shiro.web.env.EnvironmentLoader] (MSC service thread 1-6) Shiro environment initialized in 123 ms.
[0mINFO  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] Initializing Mojarra 2.2.6-jbossorg-4 20140501-1134 for context '/hc'
WARN  [org.jboss.modules] Failed to define class javax.faces.FactoryFinder in Module "javax.faces.api:main" from local module loader @732e8099 (finder: local module finder @71fcf7e2 (roots: /Users/jgreenaw/dev/apps/wildfly/wildfly-8.1.0.Final-ARQ/modules,/Users/jgreenaw/dev/apps/wildfly/wildfly-8.1.0.Final-ARQ/modules/system/layers/base)): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space

WARN  [org.jboss.modules] Failed to define class com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationAssociate in Module "com.sun.jsf-impl:main" from local module loader @732e8099 (finder: local module finder @71fcf7e2 (roots: /Users/jgreenaw/dev/apps/wildfly/wildfly-8.1.0.Final-ARQ/modules,/Users/jgreenaw/dev/apps/wildfly/wildfly-8.1.0.Final-ARQ/modules/system/layers/base)): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space...
```

followed by other services failing on load for the same reason.

I've gone and done the obvious like up'ing the permgen in maven and wildfly to 512mb then to 1024mb.  It seems something is fundamentally wrong.  I can run the entire application without adjusting anything.

Arquillian.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<arquillian xmlns="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian/arquillian_1_0.xsd">

    <container qualifier="wildfly" default="true">
        <configuration>
            <!-- Supported property names: [managementPort, username, managementAddress, 
                bundlePath, managementProtocol, cleanServerBaseDir, jbossHome, password, 
                modulePath] -->
            <property name="jbossHome">/dev/apps/wildfly/wildfly-8.1.0.Final-ARQ/</property>
            <property name="modulePath">/dev/apps/wildfly/wildfly-8.1.0.Final-ARQ/modules</property>
            <property name="javaVmArguments">-Xms64m -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -Dorg.jboss.resolver.warning=true</property>
        </configuration>
    </container>
</arquillian>
```

Relevant (i think) pom dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian</groupId>
    <artifactId>arquillian-bom</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.5.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver</groupId>
    <artifactId>shrinkwrap-resolver-impl-maven</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <!-- Remote local Profile - Arquillian will deploy the test artifact to 
                a local server, test the artifact and undeploy -->
        <id>arq-wildfly-local</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <skipTests>false</skipTests>
        </properties>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
                <artifactId>wildfly-arquillian-container-embedded</artifactId>
                <version>8.1.0.Final</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
```

past experience indicates i'm missing something fundamental, and that permgen running out is a sympton of something else i'm doing wrong.  I have tried various .import.... in the Maven resolver to no avail. Same problem command line and in eclipse.

java version "1.7.0_60"
Apache Maven 3.2.1
wildfly 8.1
OS X Latest

Question: Any idea where to go next?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just hit the same problem.  If I get anywhere I'll let you know.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using linux then you can use .bashrc profile put this command.

export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m" then reset the terminal.

Or you can set this in environment variable.

Alternatively you can set these values in Maven Command line arguments by using this command

-DXmx512m -DXX:MaxPermSize=512m

Comment: Thanks, i can change the values and I'm aware of them, it doesn't seem to matter though.  I can run the entire application inside wildfly with 1/4 of the memory without a problem.